# Codeigniter creates 0 byte files how do i prevent it?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my config file log settings like this: **$config['log_threshold'] = 0;**
But codeigniter create 0 byte files in my log folder refresh a normal page. (Please look my log folder image) how do i prevent it? Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 and PHP 5.5.32

[FTP Log Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Kji.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your index.php file;

```
$this->log->enable_logging(FALSE);
error_reporting(0);
```